# Filtering image with OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing

I am pretty new to programming. And I want to make program which is able to filtrate image from small objects and non-convex objects so only shapes such as rectangles, triangles, circles etc. stay.
What have I done so far?

I managed to obtain image in binary by two separate ways (color detection and canny function) Then I created contours with function `findContours`. So that is working flawlessly.

here's the code:

```
vector<Point> approxShape;
vector<vector<Point>> FiltredContours;
vector<vector<Point>> TRI; 
vector<vector<Point>> RECT; 
vector<vector<Point>> PENTA;

Mat WSO= Mat::zeros(im.size(), CV_8UC3); //Without Small Objects

for ( int j = 0; j < contours.size(); j++)
{
    if ((fabs(contourArea(contours[j]))) >100)
        drawContours(WSO, contours, j,Scalar(128,128,128),2,8,hiearchy,0, Point()); // to see how it looks before it goes further

    {                   
        approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[j]), approxShape, arcLength(Mat(contours[j]), true) * 0.02, true);

        if (isContourConvex(approxShape))           
        {
            FiltredContours.push_back(approxShape); 
        }
    }
}

///--------Show image after filtring small obj. -----
imshow("WSO",WSO);

////--------Filtred-Image-Drawing---------------------
Mat approxmat = Mat::zeros(imHSV.size(),CV_8UC3);
drawContours(approxmat, FiltredContours, -1,barva,2,8,hiearchy,0, Point());//drawContours(approxkresba, FiltredContours, -1,Scalar(255, 0, 0),2,8,hiearchy,0, Point());

namedWindow("Filtred objects",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Filtred objects",approxmat);
```

I tried to change parameters in `contourArea` and in `approxPollyDP` as well. It still doesn't work the way I thought it would.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: It just didnt do what it should I tried to add some pictures of outputs but they didnt let me so that's why it seems to be confusing. Anyway I maneged to figure it out. Anyway thanks for the response @Christopher Peterson.
And for those who may have the same problem try to draw contours in a cycle. And also I have the second { on the bad place. It should be before drawContours(WSO...